# Grant control of Activity UI in SDK

Tags: android, kotlin, aar

Currently we're making an Android library that contains an `Activity`. We want to control the exact flow and the state of the activity, but give the user that implements the library control what the UI looks like. Meanwhile, we want to expose the least amount of internal classes.

The SDK user may decide where views are placed, sizes, colors; we decide on what happens on onClicks and provide the texts of TextViews.

The activity makes use of a Model-View-Intent pattern, so we want to expose the immutable state. Without adjustable UI, the Activity and all its' classes are internal. With adjustable UI, a lot more classes have to made public. This increases the risk of breaking changes on updates and exposes our logic.

To expose the UI, several solution were thought of:

- Having a static callback on the activity that calls `onCreate()`, so `setContentView()` can be set, and calls `render(state: State)` on every state change. Our classes are shielded as we like, but using a static for this is questionable.
- Make the Activity open, so sdk users can subclass it. This means that every class used by the activity, has to be changed from internal to public.The classes which actually should be internal, will be hidden by obfuscating them with ProGuard.
- It would be the nicest to pass a function in the `Intent`, which to my knowlegde is not possible.
- Pass a POJO were we define parameters such as background color, which is the most restricting to the sdk user and is not in consideration.

Which solution is the best? Is there another method than the ones we thought of?

Comment: `give the user that implements the library control what the UI looks like` Can you expose everything you need using a theme?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Sdk users want to use custom views and they are allowed to additional views and control them themself. Additionally, some want to add animations too.

Comment: `It would be the nicest to pass a function in the Intent` As long as your SDK activity lives in the same process as the calling code you can store the function body in a static hash map by a generated string key, pass that key in an intent (effectively a pointer to function), and have that unpacked and executed by your activity. The `static` hash map is a hidden implementation detail. I don't think it necessarily a best practice, your users may or may not run into memory leaks... Just an idea. And it won't work across processes which are controlled by consumer.

Comment: What if you pass a class name via intent, that class has a well-known constructor and implements an interface. Your activity will then construct an instance of said class and execute whatever methods you need whenever you need them. This doesn't leak memory and can work across processes if the consumer supports it - it's not prohibited by design as in my previous example.

Comment: I implemented the static hash map, which works and what I like the most. My co-worker is in favor of letting the SDK user extend our activity, which is according to him easier to use for the SDK user and less prone to memory leaks. On creating the class via reflection: I don't like to restrict the sdk user to the only parameters I can think off

Comment: Alright, but expect issue reports from consumers in atypical setups. If the consumer has to extend the activity they also need to manually provide manifest entry for it (not that easy after all). The custom class is created by your original activity - no manifest entry. You can have a callback for populating menu and for populating a designated layout. Or have one callback with the whole activity as parameter if you want. Or both, the consumer may pick and choose what they need granularly. Going through reflection means no memory leaks from plain old callbacks from an Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The SDK user may decide where views are placed, sizes, colors; we decide on what happens on onClicks and provide the texts of TextViews.

I picture this like so:

- Your consumer receives a `State`, a `ViewGroup`, and an `Actions` object, which I'll explain later.
- Based on `State` the consumer is required to create several views and place them as they wish within supplied `ViewGroup`.
- The consumer is also required to register above views using some `Actions.register*Button` methods.
- The above logic is executed inside one callback method. Once said method finished your SDK will verify correctness (all required actions are assigned a clickable view) and proceed.

Now, how to pass this callback method to sour SDK?

### 1.

> It would be the nicest to pass a function in the Intent

This is actually possible with relative ease (and, IMO, some severe drawbacks).

In your SDK create a static `Map<Key, Callback> sCallbacks`. When your consumer registers the callback using your API, you'll generate a lookup key for it and store it within the map. You can pass the key around as an `Intent` extra. Once your SDK activity is opened it can lookup the callback using the key from its intent.

The key can be a `String` or `UUID` or whatever fits your needs and can be put inside an intent.

**Pros:**

- It's *deceptively* easy to implement and use.
- The consumer can use your SDK from just one file. All the calling code is in one place.

**Cons:**

- You're not in charge where the callback is created. The consumer may create it as an anonymous class inside an `Activity`, which results in a memory leak.
- You lose the callback map when process dies. If the app is killed while in your SDK activity you need to gracefully handle it when the app is restarted.
- Variables are not shared across multiple processes. If your SDK activity and the calling code are not in the same process, your SDK activity will not be able to find the callback. Remember that the consumer is free to change process for their activities and even override your own activity process.

The calling point would look something like `startSdk(context) { state, parent, actions -> /* ... */ }`.

This is by far the most comfortable method for the consumer, yet the weaknesses start to show once you leave the area of a typical consumer setup.

### 2.

> Make the Activity open, so sdk users can subclass it.

As you explained this is not possible without making compromies on your end.

**Pros:** ?

**Cons:**

- The consumer needs to register their subclass and unregister your original SDK activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I'm assuming the manifest merger is enabled. This *is* a pain, as I often forget to look here.
- The consumer gets *easy* access to your activity and is free to break it as they please.
- Unless your documentation is pristine, the consumer will have a hard time figuring out what to override in your activity.

The calling point would look something like `startSdk<MySdkActivity>(context)`.

I really don't understand the benefits of this option, as a consumer. I lose the benefits of #1 and gain nothing in return. As a developer I can't sanction this 'let the consumer deal with it' attitude. They will break things, you'll get bug reports and you will have to handle it eventually.

### 3.

Here I'll try to expand on the idea mentioned first in comments.

The callback would an abstract class defined by your SDK. It would be used as follows:

- The consumer extends this class and defines the callback body. The class needs to have an empty constructor and be static. Typically it would be defined in its own file.
- The class name is passed in an intent to your SDK activity.
- Your SDK activity reflectively creates an instance of the callback.

The callback class could have several methods, one could set up menu, one could setup only view hierarchy, one would get the whole activity as parameter. The consumer would pick the one they need. Again, this needs to be documented well if there are multiple options.

**Pros:**

- You separate the callback from the call site (where your SDK is called from). This is good, because the callback is executed inside *your* activity, completely separated from calling code.
- As a result you can't leak the calling activity.
- The consumer doesn't need to touch `AndroidManifest.xml`. This is great because registering your callback has nothing to do with Android. *The manifest is mainly for things that the system interacts with.*
- The callback is easily recreated after process death. It has no constructor parameters and it's stateless.
- It works across multiple processes. If, by any chance, the consumer needs to communicate across processes they're in charge of how they achieve that. Your SDK is not making it impossible as in case #2.
- You get to keep your classes `internal`.

**Cons:**

- You have to bundle a proguard rule to keep the empty constructor of each class extending the abstract callback class. You also need to keep their class names.

I'm assuming you'll hide the intent passing as an implementation detail so the entry point could look something like `startSdk<MyCallback>(context)`.

I like this one because it shifts all possible responsibilities from the consumer to you, the SDK developer. You make it hard for the consumer to use the API wrong. You shield the consumer from potential errors.

Now back to the first paragraph. As long as the consumer can get their hands on a context (`ViewGroup.getContext()`) they're able to access the activity and the application (in that process). If both the calling activity and your SDK activity live in the same process the consumer could even access their prepared Dagger component. But they don't get to override your activity methods in unexpected ways.